# "When I think to"

Tags: prepositions, translation

Yesterday I saw in a poster ad the following phrase "When I think to Modena, I recall ...". Now, IMHO it should be "think of" or "think about"; sadly, it looks like a terrible Google translation of the Italian "Quando penso a Modena, ...". But before I complain to the local authorities, is there a chance that "When I think to" might be correct?

Comment: "When I think to Modena, [...]" is, without question, not idiomatic English. The "think of" and "think about" variants are fine.

Comment: They will probably tell you they  are just trying  to be creative. Was it  *When I think to ....Modena*,  perhaps?

Comment: I'm having trouble coming up with a lot of examples of this, but I think the construction "think to your X" has some currency in parts of the US. I believe it's mostly found in rural speech. "Think to your childhood. Think to your dear old momma -- what would she say now? Think to your own habits." Certainly "think to yourself" is pretty standard. But no, probably not "think to [place name]".

Comment: If I'm not imagining it, it could be a shortened form of "think back to".

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, it looks like an incident of poor translation.

"Quando penso a Modena..." = When I think of (or about) Modena

I'm a fluent French speaker and I find the above Italian phrase very close to the French equivalent: "Quand je pense à Modena", which can only translated as:

When I think of Modena